# split field with array and join from another table

Tags: mysql

i have a master table with 'id','extras' fields

`'extras'` field is `varchar` with values like `'[10,20,30]'`.

each `id` on this field value array is linked to another table with name `'extras'` and fields `'id'`,`'descr'`.

i want to query master table and replace extras field values `'[10,20,30]'` with 'descr' field from table extras.

The result should be

```
1,'descrfromid10,descrfromid20,descrfromid30'
2,'descrfromid10,descrfromid20,descrfromid30'
3,'descrfromid10,descrfromid20,descrfromid30'
etc
```

Any idea about?

I guess i will need to `concat` and join two tables.

Thanks

Regards,
Vangelis

Comment: what did you mean by `1,2,3` in your result set? [first column]

Comment: master table record id. Autonumber field.

Comment: the record 1,'[10,20,30]' should be 1,'descr value from record 10,descr value from record 20,descr value from record 20'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with a little help from another post I make it work...

If there is a better solution please let me know :)

Thanks

```
SELECT
   m.id,
   m.extras,
   GROUP_CONCAT(c.descr SEPARATOR ",") AS cats
FROM
   vouchers AS m,
   cartypes AS c
WHERE
   FIND_IN_SET(c.id, REPLACE(REPLACE(m.extras,"[",""),"]","")) != 0
GROUP BY
   m.id;
```